# how do i display the label that more than 50% accuracy in line chart using python?

Tags: python

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5, 5])
plt.plot(data["recall"])
plt.title('256 Classes Performance')
plt.xlabel('class')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy Rate')
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

image 1 is my image, image 2 is what I want, I want to add labels for those classes which more than 50% accuracy, including class number and accuracy rate displaying in the line chart

Comment: I would plot a bar chart and color bars ge 0.5 green and lt 0.5 as red?

Comment: Here's a direction of thought: 1) find indices where `accuracy > 0.5`, 2) get a list of class labels for these indices 3) put labels at `(x=i, y=data["recall"][i])` on the plot. The first two should be easy, for the third use `ax.annotate(label_of_class, (i, data["recall"][i]))`

Comment: could you show me the code how to make that happen?

Comment: @Alexey Larionov   Could u show me the code to me, I don't know the step 3 is. Please

Comment: @Leo I gave it to you `ax.annotate(label_of_class, (i, data["recall"][i]))`. Execute it for each index of class `i`, if its accuracy is greater than 0.5

Comment: @Alexey Larionov i want something like this. i updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

my_vals = np.random.rand(50)
categories = np.arange(50)
colors = ['red' if v >= 0.5 else 'green' for v in my_vals]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4))
ax.bar(categories, my_vals, color=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `ax.annotate` and `ax.scatter`. With `xytext` you can move the text (see [matplotlib.pyplot.annotate](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html)).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.financial import pmt

y_vals = np.random.rand(50)
x_vals = np.arange(50)
annotations = [f'{y:.1f}' if y >= 0.5 else '' for y in y_vals]
dots = [y if y >= 0.5 else 9999.0 for y in y_vals]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4))

ax.set_ylim(-0.1, 1.1)
ax.plot(x_vals, y_vals)
ax.scatter(x_vals, dots, color='red')
for x, y, text_val  in zip(x_vals, y_vals, annotations):
    ax.annotate(
        text_val,
        xy=(x, y),
    )

plt.show()
```

[image]